# long write with Core Bluetooth on MacOS Sierra

Tags: core-bluetooth, macos-sierra

I've been calling Core Bluetooth's [writeValue](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518747-writevalue) with data with length >20 bytes successfully for a few years now. That is, through OSes ~10.7 (Mountain Lion) to El Capitan (10.11). Core Bluetooth would silently switch from write to long write (prepare writes and execute write) when I went over 20 bytes. With Sierra, it instead silently fails when I give it >20 bytes. The documentation says nothing about this behavior, so I suppose it's expectable that it's gone now. However, long writes are pretty fundamental and it seems crazy to me that this functionality has been dropped with no mention.

Has anyone else had this experience? Does anyone know what's happened? Do long writes work for anyone on Sierra?

Comment: Yes, I've just wasted hours of my life discovering this limitation. Are you aware of a workaround for writing characteristics longer than 20 bytes from macOS Sierra?

Comment: Rolling your own long-write mechanism....

Seems this is fixed in 10.12.2 Beta (16C41b).